# Two parameter memoization in Haskell

Tags: haskell, memoization

I'm trying to memoize the following function:

```
gridwalk x y
    | x == 0 = 1
    | y == 0 = 1
    | otherwise = (gridwalk (x - 1) y) + (gridwalk x (y - 1))
```

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208258/memoization-in-haskell) I came up with the following solution:

```
gw :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int -> Int
gw f x y
    | x == 0 = 1
    | y == 0 = 1
    | otherwise = (f (x - 1) y) + (f x (y - 1))

gwlist :: [Int]
gwlist = map (\i -> gw fastgw (i `mod` 20) (i `div` 20)) [0..]

fastgw :: Int -> Int -> Int
fastgw x y = gwlist !! (x + y * 20)
```

Which I then can call like this:

```
gw fastgw 20 20
```

Is there an easier, more concise and general way (notice how I had to hardcode the max grid dimensions in the `gwlist` function in order to convert from 2D to 1D space so I can access the memoizing list) to memoize functions with multiple parameters in Haskell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [data-memocombinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-memocombinators/0.4.1/doc/html/Data-MemoCombinators.html) package from hackage. It provides easy to use memorization techniques  and provides an easy and breve way to use them:

```
import Data.MemoCombinators (memo2,integral)

gridwalk = memo2 integral integral gridwalk' where
  gridwalk' x y
    | x == 0 = 1
    | y == 0 = 1
    | otherwise = (gridwalk (x - 1) y) + (gridwalk x (y - 1))
```

Comment: Shouldn't gridwalk call back to gridwalkMemo instaid of itself?

Comment: I'm chosing this because of brevity and vote count, but both sth's and John's answers helped me understand memoization in Haskell better, thanks!

Comment: You may need `cabal install data-memocombinators`.

Answer (score 19):

You can use a list of lists to memoize the function result for both parameters:

```
memo :: (Int -> Int -> a) -> [[a]]
memo f = map (\x -> map (f x) [0..]) [0..]


gw :: Int -> Int -> Int
gw 0 _ = 1
gw _ 0 = 1
gw x y = (fastgw (x - 1) y) + (fastgw x (y - 1))

gwstore :: [[Int]]
gwstore = memo gw

fastgw :: Int -> Int -> Int
fastgw x y = gwstore !! x !! y
```

Comment: This should be higher up. While not as easy as the others, this is by far the most insightful answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a version using `Data.MemoTrie` from the [MemoTrie](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie) package to memoize the function:

```
import Data.MemoTrie(memo2)

gridwalk :: Int -> Int -> Int
gridwalk = memo2 gw
  where
    gw 0 _ = 1
    gw _ 0 = 1
    gw x y = gridwalk (x - 1) y + gridwalk x (y - 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want maximum generality, you can memoize a memoizing function.

```
memo :: (Num a, Enum a) => (a -> b) -> [b]
memo f = map f (enumFrom 0)

gwvals = fmap memo (memo gw)

fastgw :: Int -> Int -> Int
fastgw x y = gwvals !! x !! y
```

This technique will work with functions that have any number of arguments.

Edit: thanks to Philip K. for pointing out a bug in the original code.  Originally `memo` had a "Bounded" constraint instead of "Num" and began the enumeration at `minBound`, which would only be valid for natural numbers.

Lists aren't a good data structure for memoizing, though, because they have linear lookup complexity.  You might be better off with a Map or IntMap.  Or [look](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie) [on](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-memo) [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators).

Note that this particular code does rely on laziness, so if you wanted to switch to using a Map you would need to take a bounded amount of elements from the list, as in:

```
gwByMap :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
gwByMap maxX maxY x y = fromMaybe (gw x y) $ M.lookup (x,y) memomap
 where
  memomap = M.fromList $ concat [[((x',y'),z) | (y',z) <- zip [0..maxY] ys]
                                              | (x',ys) <- zip [0..maxX] gwvals]

fastgw2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
fastgw2 = gwByMap 20 20
```

I think ghc may be stupid about sharing in this case, you may need to lift out the `x` and `y` parameters, like this:

```
gwByMap maxX maxY = \x y -> fromMaybe (gw x y) $ M.lookup (x,y) memomap
```

Comment: How can you pass `gw` to `memo` when memo expects a function of type `(a -> b)` but `gw` is `(Int -> Int -> Int)`? Also, wouldn't `minBound` produce negative indices when applied to something of type `Int`?

Comment: @Philip K - the type `b` in `a->b` unifies with `Int -> Int`, it's perfectly fine to memoize a function generator.  The negative index thing is a bug, though.  I'll edit my answer.